# Missing changes in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency, synchronization

I am working on a WFP application which contains a dynamic grid depending on the order type in question. Therefore I have bound the grid to a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

However on one screen where I allow users to paste in new orders, I noticed that sometimes not all values are persisted, typically when they paste in a large number, say 500 rows. I suspect this is because I am using Dictionary rather than `ConcurrentDictionary` so not all writes to the `Dictionary` are being persisted.

**Order Object:**

```
public interface IOrder : IDictionary<string, object>, 
{
    IOrderDataDictionary<string, object> OrderData { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderDataDictionary**

```
public class OrderDataDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IOrderDataDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(OrderDataDictionary<TKey, TValue>));
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _innerDictionary;

    #region Constructors
    public OrderDataDictionary()
    {
        _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }
    public OrderDataDictionary(int capacity)
    {
        _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
    }

    public OrderDataDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        _innerDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Adding to Dictionary:**

```
public Order ParseRows(List<string> rawRow, OrderType orderType)
{
    Order order = GenerateOrderEntryRow(orderType);
    List<string> row = rawRow.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

    foreach (BulkEntryColumnConfig column in _pasteHeader[orderType])
    {
        if (!column.IncludeInRequest || !column.AutoParse)
            continue;

        string rawVal = row[column.Index];

        if (column.DataType == typeof (string))
        {
            Log.DebugFormat("{0}:{1}", column.Name, rawVal);
            order.OrderData[column.Name] = rawVal;
        }
    }
    ...
    return order;
}
```

**Order**

```
public Order()
{
    _innerDictionary = new OrderDataDictionary<string, object>();
    OrderData = _innerDictionary;
}


public Order(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary)
{
    _innerDictionary = new OrderDataDictionary<string, object>(dictionary);
    OrderData = _innerDictionary;
}
```

**GenerateOrderEntryRow()**

```
public Order GenerateOrderRow(OrderType orderType)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> col in _columnDefinition[orderType])
    {
        dict.Add(col.Key, null);
    }

    dict["OrderType"] = orderType.ToString();
    Order row = new Order(dict);

    return row;
}
```

**Calling ParseRows()**

```
return Task<IList<Order>>.Factory.StartNew(() => {...ParseRows()...}
```

The key line is `order.OrderData[column.Name] = rawVal;` where I am adding a value to the dictionary using the indexer.

I'm never calling `Order()` which would mean a potential resizing of the underlying dictionary later. I only call Order(IDictionary dictionary) from `GenerateOrderEntryRow()` so  not unless it is being invoked somewhere else implicitly.

My question is, why are not all values stored correctly, and should I modify `Order.OrderData` to be of type `ConcurrentDictionary`? Would this solve the problem of some writes being missed?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: `ParseRows()` takes in the values for one row of data and converts it into one `Order` If I was to move that line inside the foreach, I would be instantiating a new order for each column of data, which wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Never mind. Are you using threading?

Comment: No, but I am calling `ParseRows()` inside a Task: `return Task<IList<Order>>.Factory.StartNew(() => {...ParseRows()...}`

Comment: That is the same (in this case).

Comment: Ok, so what is your conclusion?

Comment: When the backing store of the dictionary is resized, you start a new resize from another task or thread.

Comment: I've added more code showing how I am initialising the underlying dictionary. In ParseRows() I am creating a new `Order` and the underlying dictionary already has keys and null values for every column for that order type. Therefore there shouldn't be a need to resize the underlying dictionary.